# Laravel DateTime

Tags: php, laravel

This maybe a repeat question but I am seriously pissed. I am very well aware of date times but ...

I have been doing the same thing for a long time, it worked, but now it wont.

I get error:

```
Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '12/06/2016' for column 'claimed_on' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `claim_details` (`desc`, `claimed_on`, `amount_claimed`, `status`, `claim_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (expense 123, 12/06/2016, 123, pending, , 2016-12-24 09:44:02, 2016-12-24 09:44:02))
```

I am doing this:

```
$claim->claimed_on = Carbon::now();
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need pass date and time in this format like this 2016-12-24 11:23:21 I mean instead of / you need to pass -

Comment: `Carbon::now()` will generate a date in the correct format. It will not generate a date in `mm/dd/yyyy`, as far as I know. I'm guessing you are either setting this field again somewhere before the insert, or you have a `setClaimedOnAttribute` mutator on your class that is incorrect.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, `Carbon::now()` will generate today's date, not a date 18 days in the past. I think you're resetting your field somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Add `claimed_on` to [`$dates`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) variable to work with it as with Carbon instance:

```
protected $dates = ['claimed_on'];
```

Also, when creating table with migrations, use [`dateTime()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#columns):

```
$table->timestamp('claimed_on');
```

Comment: isn't better to use timestamp? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/migrations-timestamp-vs-datetime-vs-date-vs-timestamps

Comment: Both will work, but I've updated my code to use `timestamp`. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$carbon = Carbon::now();
$claimed_on = $carbon->toDateTimeString();
```

I think it should solve your problem.